# jvm_bind problem when downloading through java

Tags: java

i have written the following code to download file.

```
         java.io.BufferedInputStream in = 
          new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());

      java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filename);

            java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
             int x=0;
          while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0)
             {

       bout.write(data,0,x);
      }
        if(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("table.csv"))
       {
      updateflag=true;
       }
      if(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("quotes.csv"))
       {
      quoteupdate=true;
        }
     bout.flush();
    bout.close();
       in.close();
```

Now, when a file named "table.csv" is passed as paramenter to download function, everything works smooth. Problem is when i try to download "quotes.csv" after i download "table.csv".

The exact calling is this:

```
             url="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?    s=%5EBSESN&a=00&b=31&c=2011&d="+(month-1)+"&e="+day+"&f="+year+"&g=d&ignore=.csv";
        updateflag=true;

        downloadDB("table.csv",url);


        System.out.print("quotes to download");

        url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv? 
   s=%5EBSESN&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv";
         if(candownload==true)
        {
        downloadDB("quotes.csv",url);
         }
        candownload=false;
```

I get error saying : Unrecognized Windows Socket error:0: JVM_BIND

Now i understand JVM_BIND is saying i have a process already attached to port 80.
However, i have closed all streams at the end of my function. Why is this happening then?
Thanks in advance

Comment: and yes, the funny thing is after the error shows up, table.csv is downloaded. Quotes.csv is however not downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough privileges to post comments so my apologies for providing an answer that may not get to the exact problem.
Leaving streams open won't necessarily cause this problem AFAIK.  It's really caused by trying to bind a new Server Socket when one is already existing.  So... maybe you should check to see if your code is trying to bind a new ServerSocket every time (with the same port) the download function is called.  You really shouldn't need to do that.  Bind once, and in the accept method spawn a new thread that does the download.

Comment: thanks .. i think i know what is wrong. I was indeed binding to the same port every time the function was called , i was doing it to check if internet was connected.